# XML processing child nodes in loop using Java

Tags: java, xml, dom, xmldom, ixmldomnode

Could someone help me with Java code to get this XML processed and get the output mentioned at the end. Thanks in advance.

**XML File:**

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<Oraganization Id="123" >
    <state_name ID="1" name="Telangana">
        <city_name ID="1" name="Hyderabad">
            <school_name ID="1" school_name="Vidayalay_1">
                <record>
                    <class>1</class>
                    <TeacheName>ABC</TeacheName>
                    <NumberOfStudents>100</NumberOfStudents>
                </record>
                <record>
                    <class>2</class>
                    <TeacheName>XYZ</TeacheName>
                    <NumberOfStudents>101</NumberOfStudents>
                </record>
            </school_name>
            <school_name ID="2" school_name="Vidayalay_2">
                <record>
                    <class>1</class>
                    <TeacheName>ABC</TeacheName>
                    <NumberOfStudents>100</NumberOfStudents>
                </record>
                <record>
                    <class>2</class>
                    <TeacheName>XYZ</TeacheName>
                    <NumberOfStudents>101</NumberOfStudents>
                </record>
            </school_name>
        </city_name>
    </state_name>
    <state_name ID="2" name="Karnataka">
        <city_name ID="1" name="Banglore">
            <school_name ID="1" school_name="Bglr_Vidayalay_1">
                <record>
                    <class>1</class>
                    <TeacheName>ABC</TeacheName>
                    <NumberOfStudents>100</NumberOfStudents>
                </record>
                <record>
                    <class>2</class>
                    <TeacheName>XYZ</TeacheName>
                    <NumberOfStudents>101</NumberOfStudents>
                </record>
            </school_name>
        </city_name>
    </state_name>
</Oraganization>
```

**Expected Output:**

StateId Name    CityId  Name    SchoolID    SchoolName  class   TeacherName NumberOfStudents

1   Telangana   1   Hyderabad   1   Vidayalay_1 1   ABC 100

1   Telangana   1   Hyderabad   1   Vidayalay_1 2   XYZ 101

1   Telangana   1   Hyderabad   2   Vidayalay_2 1   ABC 100

1   Telangana   1   Hyderabad   2   Vidayalay_2 2   XYZ 101

2   Karnataka   1   Banglore    1   Bglr_Vidayalay_1    1   ABC 100

2   Karnataka   1   Banglore    1   Bglr_Vidayalay_1    2   XYZ 100

Answer (score 0):

Download an XPath 3.1 library (such as Saxon) and then execute the XPath expression

```
string-join(//record ! 
    string-join(( ancestor::state_name ! (@ID, @name),
                  ancestor::city_name ! (@ID, @name),
                  ancestor::school_name ! (@ID, @school_name),
                  class, TeacheName, NumberOfStudents), ' '), '\n')
```

Someone else might have the patience to show you a solution using DOM, but I prefer the easy way.